# How to show popup message in Pyqt5 using scheduler

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, python-3.8, apscheduler

I am working on an pyqt5 trayicon application and need to add an update feature where I created a scheduler using python apscheduler which runs in the background and checks for updates. The problem I am facing is when the updates are available I need to show a pop-up to get user consent to install updates, but when ever the whenever the pop-up function is called this message is shown in console and the application crashes or stops working.

```
NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread! This will throw an exception in the future.
```

My code snippet for reference:

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QtWidgets.QSystemTrayIcon):

    def __init__(self, icon, parent=None):
    ....
    
    def show_popup(self,message):
        msgBox = QMessageBox()
        msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox.setText(message)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle("QMessageBox Example")
        msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        msgBox.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgButtonClick)

        returnValue = msgBox.exec()
        if returnValue == QMessageBox.Ok:
            return True
        return False

    def startUpdateScheduler(self):
        scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(checkUpdate, 'interval', seconds=5)
        scheduler.start()
    
    def checkUpdate(self):
        if(updatesAvailable):
           installUpdates(self.show_popup("DeviceHub updates are available\n Do you want to install?")
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the BackgroundScheduler executes the callbacks in a secondary thread, and the OP in that thread tries to update the GUI which Qt forbids. Instead you should use QtScheduler:

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from apscheduler.schedulers.qt import QtScheduler
```

```py
def startUpdateScheduler(self):
    scheduler = QtScheduler()
    scheduler.add_job(self.checkUpdate, 'interval', seconds=5)
    scheduler.start()
```